# How to tell if a type inherits from another type not including any generic type parameters?

Tags: c#, reflection, types

I have the following:

```
public interface IContract
{
     //...
}
public interface IContractChannel : IContract, IClientChannel 
{
    //....
}

public class myClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IContractChannel>
{
   ///...
}
```

I need to determine if my client is of type ClientBase at runtime. I'm trying

```
 myClientType.IsSubClassOf(ClientBase<IClientChannel>);
```

it returns false. I don't have the IContractChannel type in hand. How can I know if my type inherits of ClientBase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for is:

```
Console.WriteLine(myClientType.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() 
  == typeof(ClientBase<>));
```

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/62nWOP).

Answer (score 2):

`ClientBase<IContractChannel>` is not the same type as  `ClientBase<IClientChannel>`, also `IContractChannel`  inherits from `IClientChannel`, it doesn't mean `ClientBase<IContractChannel>` inherits from `ClientBase<IClientChannel>`.  when the template class instantiates, they're different types.

So it should be false.

What you want to achieve,  this is a term for this: Contravariance. In MSDN, there's a topic about this: [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Contravariance enables you to use a more generic (less derived) type than originally specified, such as You can assign an instance of `IEnumerable<Base>`  to a variable of type `IEnumerable<Derived>`.

In C#, you can [create Variant Generic Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx) to support Contravariance, but for you case, the generic interface is already there.

Comment: This explains why what I'm trying does not work. However, how can I know if myClientType inherits ClientBase in this case?

Comment: You only care about the ClientBase and not the Generic typed parameter?

Comment: @ErikPhilips Exactly. The generic typed parameter can be of any type it does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can either look at the type of the Channel `myClient.Channel.GetType()`, or you can look at `myClientType.GenericTypeArguments` to get the TChannel type, then check it.

Comment: myClientType.GenericTypeArguments throws execption object not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: It might be [GetGenericArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx)